# Не рисуется canvas на неактивной вкладке

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Здравствуйте. Проблема состоит в том, что когда я запускаю рисование на одной вкладке, перехожу на вторую, а через 5 (без разницы сколько) секунд возвращаюсь обратно на ту вкладку, где начал рисовать canvas, и замечаю, что за время моего отсутствия на этой вкладке canvas не прорисовался ни на один процент даже. Кто знает, в чем проблема? Баг не только в моем коде, но и в сторонних библиотеках, например `d3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это фича метода [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) который предпочитает сохранять процессорное время на не активных вкладках - что на самом деле хорошо, он специально заточен для выполнения эффективной анимации в браузерах

Ну у вас он скорее всего и вызывается, потому что такие функции как `setTimeOut` и `setInterval` такой возможностью не обладают - тоесть на неактивных вкладках анимация продолжает своё выполнение